# After updating Gradle dependencies failed to resolve

Tags: android, gradle

After update gradle to latest dependencies contain firebase and play services:

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Failed to resolve: play-services-base
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-stats
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-ads-identifier
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-basement
Open File

*build.gradle(app)*

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: simply put it says don't use compile in your gradle file to sync libraries, instead use implements.

Comment: i used implementation but failed to resolve.

Comment: can you make sure you are not working on gradle offline mode right

Comment: yes,i working on online mode

Comment: can you post logs

Comment: Do you reference the google maven repository?

Comment: i resolved this issue,and after that i build app on Bitrise Ci,working well,thanks all,see solution below

Answer (score 20):

I resolved issue.
This is solution

```
1.add google() before jcenter()
2.exclude group:"com.google.android.gms" in facebook sdk dependencies
```

My code 
Gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

// something here ...

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Myapp/gradle :

```
repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   google()
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.28.0'){
    exclude group:"com.google.android.gms"
}
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'

implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation files('libs/glide-3.8.0.jar')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
}
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Was bagging head for almost 2 days. This solution relieved me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and resolved by this:

In Gradle (project), just change the position of `google()` before `jcenter()`, and Sync and the error is gone.

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is the explanation. Someone had the `brilliant` idea of uploading to JCenter only the `pom` definition for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1` meaning that if JCenter was your first option, it would find the `POM` file and would attempt to download the `AAR` from the same location, but it hasn't been upload there. Switching the repositories order with `google()` now first, it will find both the POM and AAR correctly on Google's repository.

Running `gradle app:build` from command line would tell you what `Android Studio` doesn't:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
```

You can see the artifact on JCenter's website, it only contains the POM.

https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.android.gms%3Aplay-services-basement#files/com%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fgms%2Fplay-services-basement%2F15.0.1

While Google repository has the complete set:

- https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar